# Updating Windows 10 is not working

Tags: windows-10

I'm trying to install update (KB4015438) using control panel. It is not working (it sticks to 63% and doesn't move. In log files it is logged that it has failed yesterday and some time before that. I've downloaded the update file manually, but it can't install.

I think there is something about the update "system" on my PC. How can I fix it?

Comment: share the CBS log folder C:\windows\logs\CBS (compressd in a zip on OneDrive)

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/?v6m49l67q0kudy9

Comment: I can't see any failures in the log. Install KB4016635 which is a bit more recent: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4016635

Comment: were you able to install this weeks updates via WindowsUpdate?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to get this update via offline installers. Check your architecture before downloading.

**KB4015438**

**32 bit** - http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2017/03/windows10.0-kb4015438-x86_606c46678437af9b14599ad74e6a57b2b997d9ff.msu

**64 bit** - http://download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/updt/2017/03/windows10.0-kb4015438-x64_c0e4b528d1c6b75503efd12d44d71a809c997555.msu

Comment: he already tried this : **I've downloaded the update file manually, but it can't install.**

Comment: What kind of error does it giving? Screenshot please!